# Efficiency in a use of ParallelMap[]

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, parallelization, scoping

Suppose `M` is a **large** and **relatively dense** **symbolic** matrix. I am interested in applying `F[]` (`F[]` could be for example `Together[]` or any other function that threads over lists) on each *column* of `M`. To do so, I wrote the following code, which takes as an advantage the fact `F[]` threads over lists

```
pF[myMatrix_]:=Module[{out},out=Transpose[ParallelMap[F,Transpose[myMatrix]]]
```

In computing `pF[M]`, I find the code to work well, but only once the parallel kernels start being busy. That is there's a long delay before `F/@` start being applied.

I am aware that this issue is (probably) due to the overhead caused by the master kernel to communicate M to the slave kernels. At this point, I am seeking for suggestions minimizing this issue.

**Note 1**: I have access to powerful machines (16 cores and about 800 GB of RAM), so I am open to exotic suggestions!

**Note 2**: I tried both `Method->"FinestGrained"` and `Method->"CoarsestGrained"` and find the former to speed the calculation up considerably. I expect varying completion time depending on the column at hand, so to me this was not so surprising.

**Note 3**: I also tried

```
pF[myMatrix_]:=Module[{out},
upB=First@Dimensions@myMatrix;
holdMat=Hold@@myMatrix;
out=ParallelTable[F[Evaluate[holdMat[[i,All]]]],{i,upB}]
```

and find it works slower.

Comment: You can control what is distributed. Use `ParallelMap[..., DistributedContexts->None]` to turn off automatic distribution. To make definitions on kernels, use [`DistributeDefinitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) or [`ParallelEvaluate[..., DistributedContexts->None]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html).

Comment: If the function threads over lists, then what is the difference between applying it to column, rows, or the entire matrix?

Comment: At user293787 Thanks, that is likely to be what I needed! 

@Szabolcs I agree that in general this should not make a difference. However, for my particular M, I minimize the # of kernels in idle by doing it on column.

Comment: Is that because you have only a few rows, or because there is a large difference in the time it takes to process different rows?

Comment: Is it the case that `F` is very fast, and the reason why the computation takes so long is that the matrix is large? If so, there might not be a good way out of this. The function `F` should be significantly faster for one matrix element than the time it takes to transfer one matrix element through MathLink. Since you have a symbolic matrix, MathLink transfer will be generally slow.

Comment: It is the latter.